# MongoDB aggregation query optimization: $match, $lookup and double $unwind

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

Let's say we have two collections:

- `devices`: the objects from this collection have (among others) the fields `name` (string) and `cards` (array); each part from that array has the fields `model` and `slot`. The cards are not another collection, it's just some nested data.
- `interfaces`: the objects from this collection have (among others) the fields `name` and `owner`.

Extra info:

- for `cards`, I'm only interested in the ones where `slot` is a number
- for a `part` of a `device` that matches the previous condition, there is an `interface` object in the other collection where the `owner` fields has as value the `name` of the `device` in cause and the name is `s[slot]p1` (the character 's' + the slot of that part + 'p1')

My job is to create a query to generate a summary of all the existing cards in all of those devices, each entry being enriched with information from the `interfaces` collection. I also need to be able to parametrize the query (in case I'm interested only in a certain device with a certain name, only a certain model for cards etc.)

So far, I have this:

```py
mongo_client.devices.aggregate([
    # Retrieve all the devices having the cards field
    {
        "$match": {
            # "name": "<device-name>",
            "cards": {
                "$exists": "true"
            }
        }
    },
    
    # Group current content with every cards object
    {
         "$unwind": "$cards"
    },
    
    # Only take the ones having "slot" a number
    {
        "$match": {
            "cards.slot": {
                "$regex": "^\d+$"
            }
        }
    },
    
    # Retrieve the device's interfaces
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "interfaces",
            "let": {
                "owner": "$name",
            },
            "as": "interfaces",
            "pipeline": [{
                "$match": {
                    "$expr": {
                        "$eq": ["$owner", "$$owner"]
                    },
                },
            }]
        }
    },
    
    {
        "$unwind": "$interfaces"
    },
    
    {
        "$match": {
            "$expr": {
                "$eq": ["$interfaces.name", {
                    "$concat": ["s", "$cards.slot", "p1"]
                }]
            }
        }
    },
    
    # Build the final object
    {
        "$project": {
            # Card related fields
            "slot": "$cards.slot",
            "model": "$cards.model",

            
            # Device related fields
            "device_name": "$name",
           
            # Fields from interfaces
           "interface_field_x": "$interfaces.interface_field_x",
           "interface_field_y": "$interfaces.interface_field_y",
        }
    },
])
```

The query works and it's quite fast, but I have a question:

1. Is there any way I can avoid the 2nd `$unwind`? If for every `device` there are 50-150 `interface` objects where `owner` is the name of that device, I feel that I'm slowing it down. Every device has a unique interface named `s[slot]p1`. How can I get that specific object in a better way? I tried to use two `$eq` expressions in the `$match` inside the `$lookup` or even `$regex` or `$regexMatch`, but I couldn't use the outside `slot` fields, even if I put it inside `let`.
2. If I want to parametrize my query to filter the data if needed, would you add match expressions as intermediary steps or just filter at the end?

Any other improvements to the query are welcome. I'm also interested in how to make it errors proof (if by mistake `cards` is missing or that `s1p1` interface is not found.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is missing sample data for the query, but:

- Merge the third stage into the first stage, get rid of $exists
- Instead of pipeline use localField+foreignField, pipeline is much slower

The number of unwinds in the query should correspond to what objects you want in the result set:

- 0 unwinds for devices
- 1 unwind for cards
- 2 unwinds for interfaces

To *match* the desired conditions no unwinds are needed.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the advice. I completely missed the fact that I can filter the `slots` before unwind. `localField` + `foreignFields` is what I had before, but I thought a `pipeline` might be better. So I guess I could just get all the interfaces of a device and then just use a `$match` to get the `s[slot]p1` one. In this case, is the `$unwind` still necessary or there's a better way to do it? (that match after lookup is supposed to return just one element, maybe 0 in case something is wrong).

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying. If you want to revise your question feel free to do that, edit your question to say what you want it to say.

Comment: I was asking if the 2nd `$unwind` (for interfaces) can be avoided since there's always just one object with the name `s[slot]p1` or no object at all. Unwind for an array with a single element seems too much. Is array indexing better/safer or I should just stick to unwind?

Comment: You should index the fields that are used for retrieving the documents in the first stage. Unwind doesn't retrieve documents hence isn't affected by indexes.